# .NET Entity Framework automatically joining tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, entity-framework-4

I'm have a table `Files` with a list of file names etc. and has a foreign key set up to a table called `FileTypes`. I'm trying to just get a list of FileTypes for a drop down list and for some reason it is automatically joining on the Files table and returning a huge list of duplicates and instead of giving me the FileType.Id it is giving me the Files.Id

I've tried the do a straight SqlDataAdapter with select statement in code behind SqlDatasource on the page and EntityDataSource and nothing seems to work. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: please post your code. Thanks !

Comment: You talk about using Entity framework and using SqlDataAdapter.  Please clarify.  Is that one attempt or two different tries?

Comment: It is two different tries. I am using EF everywhere else in the site but for some reason its just this one thing that always automatically joins the two tables.

Comment: Going to try a stored procedure and see if that does it too.